# Prove that coefficients of cusp form are always in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: modular-forms

I have trouble trying to prove that the cusp form $\Delta$ has always integer coefficients. Using 
\begin{equation}
\Delta = (E_4^3-E_6^2)/1728
\end{equation}
And knowing that
\begin{equation}
E_4 = 1-\frac{8}{B_4}q-\frac{8}{B_4}\sum_{n\geq 2}\sigma_3(n)q^n
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E_6 = 1-\frac{12}{B_6}q-\frac{12}{B_6}\sum_{n\geq 2}\sigma_5(n)q^n
\end{equation}

I calculated $E_4^3-E_6^2$ by hand and the first coefficient of $q$ is indeed $1728$. The coefficiente of $q^2$ is $-41472$ which is divisible by $1728$. I also calculated the coefficient of $q^3$ ($435456$) but for $q^k$, $k\geq 4$ it is not obvious if its coefficient is divisible by $1728$ without evaluating the expression explicitly. What can I do?

Comment: You could try to the Jacoi product factorization, which clearly has integral coefficients when expanded.

Comment: You can see this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2327018/72031) where I directly prove that $$E_{4}^{3}-E_{6}^{2}=1728q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{n})^{24}$$ so that $\Delta $ has integer coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well known that
$$\Delta=q\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)^{24}.$$

On the other hand
$$E_4=1+240\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n) q^n=1+480f(q)$$
and
$$E_6=1-504\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_5(n) q^n=1-504g(q)$$
where $f$ and $g$ have integer coefficients. Then
$$E_4^3-E_6^2=720f(q)+172800f(q)^2+13824000f(q)^3
+1008g(q)-254016g(q)^2
\equiv 720f(q)+1008g(q)=144(5f(q)+7g(q))\pmod{1728}.$$
We need to prove that $5f(q)+7g(q)\equiv0\pmod{12}$.

The $q^n$ coefficient of $5f(q)+7g(q)$ is
$$5\sigma_3(n)+7\sigma_5(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}
(5d^3+7d^5).$$
All that remains to to is to prove that $5d^3+7d^5$ is always
a multiple of $12$.